# PyTorch CUDA Out of memory

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to run a modeling  script using pytorch.I tried batch processing where I am sending only 30 videos at a time to my model.

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py", line 988, in forward
    return F.prelu(input, self.weight)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1319, in prelu
    return torch.prelu(input, weight)
**RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.19 GiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 7.43 GiB already allocated; 535.31 MiB free; 10.58 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
^M 83%|████████▎ | 5/6 [00:39<00:07,  7.82s/it]**
```

I am trying to understand what this error is indicating? Any advice on what could be done?

Comment: The error indicates that it needs more GPU memory =] Reduce to the smallest batch size = 1 and increase from there.

Comment: Also you can accumulate gradient for multiple steps (say `32`) and perform single optimizer step on that in order to stabilize loss.